# SQL Azure query performance is better with statistics?

Tags: .net, azure, performance, azure-sql-database

I have .NET web application deployed to MS Azure with an Azure SQL database in a testing environment. AzureSQL is using "Standard S1: 20DTUs" pricing tier.

One of the queries executed by application is running very slow (15 sec), so I digged deeper:

- 15 sec in application
- 2 sec from my computer using SQL Server Management Studio against same database with same credentials
- 15 sec same application, but from my computer using same connection string, debugging in visual studio
- 2 sec same application, my computer, VS, but I injected "SET STATISTICS IO ON" on the begin of problematic query.
- 200 msec same application, same database, same data,  on my SQL Server v14.0 Development edition (it is ok to be faster than SQL Azure, it is only here for comparison)

What is causing this strange behavior, i.e. difference between application and SQL Server Management Studio?

Of course, query can be somehow optimized using indexes or so, but it is not the point.

Comment: It seems, that indexes was missing on TEST database. But it is not explaining, why queries with statistics are faster than others... ?

Comment: SQL Server builds and caches execution plans based on (1) a hash of the SQL batch and (2) the connection's current `@@OPTIONS` value. Most applications connect with `SET ARITHABORT OFF` but SSMS (by default) connects with `SET ARITHABORT ON`, so there's one difference. Injecting `SET STATISTICS IO ON` into the SQL batch changes it, hence the hash of the batch is different, so SQL Server generates a potentially different execution plan than what was cached previously.